# how to use Jenkins conditionals?

Tags: jenkins, conditional-statements

I have a flow inside a simple project, I want to do the following if the day is Saturday I want to run job A else I would like job B to run, schematically like this:

DAY = $(date+"%A")

if($DAY == Saturday){ build("RunTrunkManager")}

else{build("RunMicroManager")}
[image]

Answer (score 0):

ok so the way to this is realize that inside of flows like these jenkins uses a language called groovy. So this should be and easy else if statement: 
[image]